# What negatives can occur when installing mismatched memory?

Tags: memory, voltage

Specifically, if I have a machine spec'd for 1.5V and I install 1.3V RAM modules, what side effects can occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know of ANY DDR3 1.35V memory which will not work at 1.5V.

1.5V memory is *not* guaranteed to operate to specs at 1.35V.
1.35V memory *IS* guaranteed to operate to specs at 1.5V.

This is made plain by surveying the component specification datasheets for DDR3 and DDR3L memory devices.

See also: [1.35 V RAM in a 1.5 V system - Will it fry or overclock?](https://superuser.com/questions/564175/1-35-v-ram-in-a-1-5-v-system-will-it-fry-or-overclock)

Comment: Going from 1.35V to 1.5V is an 11% overvoltage. That *might* work, or it might *not*; I certainly *would not* want to take the chance unless, perhaps, I had a couple of memory modules laying around literally collecting dust. Can you provide references supporting your claim that it *is guaranteed* to work correctly (for *any* combination of motherboard and memory module specified for operation at the respective voltages), or is this just your own, otherwise unsupported, personal opinion? Note: "personal experience" answers can be valid, but they should clearly state that that's what they are.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: The answer is correct. 1.35V modules can operate at 1.5V. This is JEDEC spec. http://superuser.com/questions/564175/1-35-v-ram-in-a-1-5-v-system-will-it-fry-or-overclock

Comment: @DragonLord Fair enough, but with the answer as it was when I wrote that comment there was no indication in the answer of that being the case.

Answer (score 4):

I would not mis-match voltages. When the System turns on it *should* detect the voltages and adjust correctly. Not all RAM and motherboards handle this equally well.

But if they are mismatched on the on the same channel especially you might not have RAM detected properly, or it might be unstable or not boot. I would expect at least an unstable environment. Mismatching just about anything else is A-OK, but voltages should always match.

Answer (score 2):

Your machine could explode.

No, the worst that could happen is that you fry the memory stick that is not rated for the higher voltage. However, it may also work. Overclockers take advantage of additional headroom in computer components all of the time including over-volting memory.

Answer (score -1):

Then, the 1,3V RAM modules won't work. If they have voltage protection, they won't be damaged (and probably, they won't damage the pc).

When you switch on the pc the next time, before loading your OS, a message will appear explainig the problem. If it's not critical (if you still can use the pc because the new ram will be ignored), it will be written "press F12 to continue", and your OS will load.