# Do I need to get identical ram to upgrade a laptop?

Tags: windows-8, memory, lenovo-laptop

I just purchased a Lenovo laptop and I need to expand the RAM. It currently has one stick of ram in it a 4GB DDR3 PC3-12800 Unbuffered NON-ECC 1.35V 1024Meg x 64 by SK Hynix and is capable of having a maximum of 8GB.

I was curious if I needed to buy a pair that matches it perfectly (I've always bought ram in pairs). I really just want to buy one more 4GB stick of RAM and I'm curious if it would be okay if I bought a matching specs wise one of a different brand or if I needed to find one the matches identically to the one I have.

Comment: Might I suggest altering/rescoping your question a little? Product recs are off topic here, but the first part of your question is pretty useful. At first glance, I assumed it was a dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/376784/how-does-motherboard-and-cpu-affect-ram-choice but on thinking about it, maybe not. I'd add that if you hit 20 rep anywhere, you can use chat, and we tend to welcome questions/discussion on hardware choices on root access, our site chatroom.

Comment: You don't need to match RAM unless your system demands it. If there is a second RAM slot on the system, just purchase the correct type, but don't worry about matching brand, speeds, or other factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need 'identical' ram to run your ram in dual channel mode, which has a slight speed boost for two identical sticks of ram.

There's a few things to consider here. Firstly, if I recall correctly, one of your ram slots *may* be under your keyboard, and a second one in an easy to access bay at the base of your system. Switching both sticks is hard.

Secondly, you could go for a stick of ram with *different* specs, and it will work as two separate channels with no issue.

Identical ram of a different brand *should* work in theory. However, there's a few reasons ram is sold as 'kits'. Its easier (for a new build), *some* systems have compatibility issues, and some manufacturers wouldn't validate a system with mismatched drives.

You *should* be fine for dual channel as long as you match frequency (same frequency as your current ram is a sensible option anyway since all your ram runs at the same clockspeed as your slowest ram), CAS timings, and *number and type of ram chips on the ram SODIMM* (which is tricky...).

Wikipedia has a ton on useful information on [dual channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture?oldformat=true) ram, which I have referenced here.