# Can I upgrade the RAM for MacBook Pro Intel Core Duo 2.16 GHz Version 10.6.8

Tags: memory

Can I upgrade my MacBook Pro 2.16 Ghz Intel Core Duo Version 10.6.8 from 2GB RAM to 4GB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell what RAM will fit my computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/18995/how-can-i-tell-what-ram-will-fit-my-computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you will not be able to use that 4GB. The problem is with the older Core Architecture [(Intel Code Duo, Yonah)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yonah_%28microprocessor%29) . This is a x86 platform and hence addressable space is constrained to ~3GB.