# How can I find out which type of RAM I need for my laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell what RAM will fit my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/18995/how-can-i-tell-what-ram-will-fit-my-computer)

I just bought an HP Laptop at Fry's and it has 6 GB of memory. I want to upgrade to 
8. The problem is that I don't know exactly what I need. I know it has 2 slots (Dual channel)
and it's DDR3.

I don't know if it is SODIMM, or how many pins it has or MHz.

I have posted some specs about my laptop:

[image]

[image]

What exact type of RAM do I need?

Comment: Ummmmmm .... NO

Comment: Why though? Especially the second answer suggesting Crucial is very useful. We encourage canonical questions and answers that apply to any case, not too localized ones.

Comment: Agreed, Crucial.com's memory tool has never failed me once over the years.

Comment: @slhck Wait.. What do you mean by duplicate?
I possibly misunderstood what you said

Comment: Questions can be closed as a duplicate of another, which basically just inserts a link at the top of your question for future reference. In your case, it so happens that we already have a community guide on buying RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any 204 pin DDR3 1333 will work.  I use 2 of these in my system.

You probably only need one chip.  I would double check your notebook that it has a 4gb and a 2gb and upgrade the 2gb one.

Comment: Yea I only need one.Also does it matter what brand they are?
I mean would it be better if they were both from the same brand?
And what are some good RAM brands?

Comment: Not really.  Just check the reviews.  G.Skill is solid stuff.  Been using their value ram for years and many systems.

Comment: Do you recommend me purchasing them from newegg?
I usually purchases stuff from Amazon or Frys
Also I'm using Hyundai electronics RAM which I've never heard about
lol

Comment: Same thing from amazon.  http://www.amazon.com/G-Skill-PC3-10666-Series-single-laptop/dp/B002IVGFN0/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1336181367&sr=8-1

Hyundai is fine.  My dell came with that.

Comment: Ok so once I remove the 2gb chip then I insert the new one and turn on my laptop then my laptop automatically detects it?

Edit: Also it's not SODIMM right?

Comment: Most of the time mixing RAM brands isn't a big deal, but I always recommend people to use the exact same RAM sticks if possible for their computers to avoid the off chance of incompatible memory.  If you look at the 4 GB chip inside the computer, you should be able to get the model number of the chip and punch that into Newegg to find a similar one you could pair it up with.

Comment: Just to make sure. It is SoDimm because it's a laptop right?
And SoDimm stands for SDRAM right?