# Advice Required for 2 GB RAM for Dell inspiron 1564

Tags: memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell what RAM will fit my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/18995/how-can-i-tell-what-ram-will-fit-my-computer)

I want to increase the RAM size of my laptop from 2GB to 4GB. I want advice on company, RAM type(DDR3?) and other things related to buying a RAM.

Comment: Welcome to superuser. See [memory upgrade](http://superuser.com/search?q=memory+upgrade) - Note: shopping questions ("advice on company") are [off topic](http://superuser.com/faq). RAM type depends on specific machine. Ability to add memory depends on available slots and on machine limits. 32-bit OS can't use all 4GB.

Comment: Processsor is Core I3, so it is 64 bit.. i want to know the best company name and ram with latest technology

Comment: We all do, but this Q&A site is not suited to *discussions* of "best company name" or "latest  technology" - the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) explains. Also, vendors used to sell 64-bit hardware with 32-bit operating systems. It's the OS that matters.

Answer (score 1):

You want a 4GB DDR3 PC3-10600 (or PC3-8500) SODIMM. Any one should do, more or less, but Crucial offers one that is guaranteed compatible for around $19, part number [CT2151387](http://www.crucial.com/store/mpartspecs.aspx?mtbpoid=620724C5A5CA7304).