# Buying RAM for laptop

Tags: laptop, memory, ddr3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell what RAM will fit my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/18995/how-can-i-tell-what-ram-will-fit-my-computer)

Ok, I got a Sony Vaio, and it has a 2GB DDR3 RAM. I installed [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) and the results said:

> 2.00 GB Single-Channel DDR3 @ 665MHz

So, now if I want to upgrade my RAM by another 2GB, what do I go and say in the hardware shop?

Answer (score 0):

Do you intend to simply purchase the Ram and put it in yourself?  If so, then you should identify where the Ram goes in your laptop, you should open that compartment, you should examine the sticker on the Ram that is currently in your laptop, you should write down what it says on that sticker, and you should use that information to purchase more Ram.

Do you intend to just bring your laptop to a repair shop and allow them to install the new Ram?  If so, then do that.  It doesn't require any further input from you.

If you REALLY want to insist on using software to identify your Ram, before you actually will be physically examining it, then use [CPU-Z (CPUID)](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) for it will not only tell you how much Ram you have and what speed it is running at, it will tell you who made the Ram, the individual product ID of each stick of Ram, what speed it is supposed to run at, which slot it is in, etc.

Comment: For now, I'll stay away from dissecting my laptop. I will use CPUZ and get it to a shop.<br>Thanks

Comment: It isn't dissecting your laptop.  See, why is it important in *any* way for you to know what kind of Ram is in your laptop, if you are going to pay technicians to worry about adding more Ram?  They are going to physically examine what's there and match it up anyway, regardless of what you tell them.  In fact, they are going to listen politely to what you tell them, and then put that information aside in favor of what they discover themselves.  Why?  Because replacing Ram is easy, and if you are leaving it to them, they will assume you are wrong in the information you are giving them.

Comment: Ha Ha, last line was funniest, but agonizingly true. :D