# Will 2 1GB Sticks of RAM Fit My New Computer?

Tags: memory

I was wondering if a pair of old 1GB RAM sticks will fit into my [new computer](http://www.freshtechsolutions.co.uk/amd-6400k-4-1ghz-1tb-8gb-1600mhz-hd-graphics-z3-plus-computer-windows-8.html)?

Information I can find on the sticks are the following:

- 1GB 1xR8 PC2 - 6400U - 666 - 12 - ZZ
- Made In China
- M378T2863EHS (Serial Code?) - CF7  0926
- SAMSUNG

Any Help Would Be Gladly Accepted! 
edit: I only want to know so when I  get my new computer, I don't waste time trying to fit new RAM sticks that will raise RAM to 10gb?

Comment: Fianlly Found Out How To Bulletpoint :/

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_Access_Memory 
Look at RAM types.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell what RAM will fit my computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/18995/how-can-i-tell-what-ram-will-fit-my-computer)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but it won't fit.
M378T2863EHS is:

> 1GB 240p PC2-6400 CL6 8c 128x8 **DDR2-800** 1Rx8 1.8V UDIMM from Samsung

as seen in MemoryTen: http://www.memoryten.com/p/016631.htm

Your new PC has  F2A88XM-DS2 motherboard from Gigabyte that suppports only DDR3 RAM:
http://www.gigabyte.pl/products/page/mb/ga-f2a88xm-ds2rev_30/specs/

But don't worry, DDR2 is less efficent and more expensive type of RAM. That's why DDR3 took it place.

Answer (score 0):

How old? RAMs have different pin layouts for different types so that an old type of RAM (say, DDR) won't fit a new slot such as your new computer's (DDR3).

[Here's a large picture of some old and fairly contemporary computer components](http://maliy.net/computer-hardware-chart1.jpg). Check the pin layouts of RAMs on the lower left. You may perhaps identify your old RAM.