# How to know which memory RAM I can use on my laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory

I've been needing to buy a new memory RAM for my laptop, but as I'm new on this type of things, and from the Internet I found out it can't be any random memory RAM, I am not sure which memory RAM I need to buy so it will work on my laptop.

I know that my actual RAM says this:
***4GB 2Rx8 PC3-10600S-09-10-F2*** (DDR3)

I've tried to find that memory RAM on google but it was unavailable, creating the need of searching for a new one.

I've heard crosair is a good one about memory RAM's, but I don't know which ones are compatible with my computer, which one will let my computer boot if I place it there.

I know that it needs to be DDR3, and need to have "PC3-10600" which I don't yet know what it is. On the task manager it says the RAM is 1333Mhz. Which would lead me to:

```
1333Mhz
PC3-10600
DDR3
Either 4GB or 2GB
```

There is also something about voltage, but how do I see which one I need to have? I found out a RAM which is:

```
SODimm DDR3 4GB Corsair CL9 1333Mhz and 2GB version
```

Yet I get no more information from the website that's selling (I am buying from portuguese websites due to Portugal being where I live)

I kinda need help about what should I know and look for when buying a new RAM for my laptop.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. See the related question: [How can I tell what RAM will fit my computer?](http://superuser.com/q/18995/87805).

Comment: Thank you. I've already seen that link, but the crucial says there are no available or needed upgrades, and CPU-Z says I have PC3-10700 Ram when in the photo I have it says PC3-10600. So I am a little bit confused. Also, with a samsung memory, can I use a corsair memory?

Comment: Yes, you can mix brands. You just need the same type (e.g. DDR3 SoDIMM, at least the same speed (else things will slow down to the lower commonly shared speed) and sometimes you run into limits by either the memory controller (which thse days is on the CPU), on the OS (e.g. 32 bit versions with no PEA) or from the motherboard (e.g. insufficient copper traces to the memory slots).

But as Kernorb already commented. This has been asked before. Quite often even. VTC duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the RAM is DDR3 and 1333MHz, you'll be fine. It's always best to find the same brand, but that isn't the most important thing.

Comment: So SODimm DDR3 4GB Corsair CL9 1333Mhz will work on my laptop even if it doesn't say PC3-10600? I read somewhere that it didn't work because it was PC3-10700 when his old one was PC3-10600, won't anything be wrong as it doesn't say if it's PC3-10600 or any other?

Comment: No. As long as it's also laptop RAM, you don't have to worry. Laptop  RAM looks about 3 inches wide, while desktop RAM is more like 7.

Comment: Are laptops ram the one that say "SODimm"?

Comment: Yes. SODIMM is laptop. DIMM is desktop.

Comment: Thank you very much, will then probably buy that one. Hope it works without a problem.

Comment: Also it's important whether it is PC3L (DDR3L) or PC3 (DDR3).The L stands for Low voltage and is often found in laptops. I bought a laptop with an extra RAM chip which was the wrong one and was causing a lot of games to crash because of that.