# How to find the correct memory for my ASUS Desktop PC

Tags: memory, upgrade, compatibility, ddr3

I have a `Asus CM6850` desktop computer and it's got four ram slots, two are used (2x4GB = 8GB) and I wanted to get another `16GB` of RAM but I'll be out of luck, I found that it only supports up to `16GB`of RAM here: https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/ASUS/essentio-cm6850.

Comment: Note that this question might be a better fit for [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Manufacturers usually have memory compatibility lists. There you can see which memory modules have been tested to be working in your motherboard. You should check that out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell what RAM will fit my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/18995/how-can-i-tell-what-ram-will-fit-my-computer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crucial.com has a memory tool, telling you the type of memory for most models of computers. Enter the make and model onto their website and they will list compatible memory.

For your model, they suggest DDR3L-1600 UDIMMs.