# Could I install the new RAM myself?

Tags: memory

My PC comes with Gibyte b365 hd3 atx 1151 motherboard (I think it has 4 memory slots and dual channel) and Corsair DDR4 2x8GB 2666 RAM, PNY RTX 2070 SUPER TRIPLE FAN graphics and supernova 650 gold power supply.

I want to expand to 32GB and I wanted to know:

With the previous configuration is it possible / recommended to expand to 32GB?
Do I have to expand with the same configuration (2x8GB) and with the same RAM? If not, I listen to recommendations.
Could I install the new RAM myself? Is it difficult considering that I never installed one? Any tutorial?
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell what RAM will fit my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/18995/how-can-i-tell-what-ram-will-fit-my-computer)

Answer (score 1):

Gigabyte B365 HD3 supports [up to 64 GB of RAM](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B365-HD3-rev-10/sp#sp) in its 4 slots, that's up to 16 GB per slot. Try to get memory from the [compatibility list](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Memory/mb_memory_b365-hd3.pdf) - modules that aren't listed may work, but it's not guaranteed.

You can mix new memory modules with those you already have, just install new ones in free slots. In this case it would be best to get 2666 MHz modules, because all installed modules have to work with the same speed and in case of mismatch faster modules will underclock to match the slowest one. So buying slower modules will slow down the ones you have currently installed and faster ones will work at 2666 MHz anyway.

You could buy a 2x16 GB kit and replace current 2x8 GB, but you won't gain anything except for 2 free slots for potential expansion in the future. I'd just add another 2x8 GB, 32 GB in total is plenty of RAM. Going for 48 GB is also an option if you'll actually benefit from that much memory (some heavy workloads would, but for gaming it won't change a thing).

Installing RAM is easy. You have to unscrew the side panel, place RAM module in its slot and press the tab to secure it - done. I'm sure you'll find a tutorial on YouTube.

Comment: i'll try. Thank you so much.@gronostaj

Comment: It is important to read your manual. It explains rules on installing RAM which can vary by model or vendor. If you do not have it, you can download from vendor's site.